# Обход блокировок

Tags: windows, firewall, командная-строка, osi

У нас со стороны провайдера заблокированы многие сети (список очень большей) в том числе и youtube.com. Раньше не обращал внимание и пользовался различными VPN (и то найти который работает. Многие тупо заблокированы). А теперь решил понять как они блокируют? На каком уровне? Подмена IP в DNS? Файрвол? первый что сделал чтобы проверить это выполнил команду tracert google.com (который работает и так) вывелся как положено ip и маршрут. После выполнил tracert youtube.com и получил ip 127.0.0.1 и маршрут состоял естественно из одного пункта это компьютер. В файле host ничего не сказано про youtube.com. Это получается DNS выдает не тот ip? Что скажете и что посоветуете? Извините если задал вопрос не туда

Comment: А если попробовать через другой dns?

Comment: @Qwertiy нет не помогает. Изменил ip DNS primary на гуглский a secondary на яндекс dns. Изменил настройки DNS и на компьютере так и на маршрутизаторе. Не помогает все равно выдает 127.0.0.1. tracert на оба dns проходит успешно

Comment: Ссылка на локалхост в трассировке это странно. Вы уверены что Вам провайдер доступ перекрыл? Потому что это очень похоже что блокировка сработала самом компе.

Comment: @alex Roosso вывод сделал я изза того что у нас один провайдер во всей стране. И у всех не работают youtube.com(и другие). Что выдает другие компьютеры на команду tracert я не знаю. И еще одно подтверждение что с помощью vpn все работает

Comment: Монополисты это плохо... А как вы к провайдеру подключаетесь. Если через роутер провайдера, то они их могут прошивать... А вообще конечно странно. Тут наверное вопрос исследований как именно делает этот Ваш провайдер. А у нас делают вот так: https://www.rbc.ru/technology_and_media/07/09/2017/59b00e269a79475c24ccf090

Comment: @alex Roosso даже сейчас вы послали мне ссылку она не открывается без впн. Еще одна чего я не понял при tracert google.com маршрут стоял через сервера провайдера и потом доходил до гугл а при tracert youtube.com он даже сервера не показывает один прыжок и это сам 127.0.0.1. А роутер простой тп линк. Не думаю что прошивали их. А как это проверять?

Comment: @alex Roosso Роутер покупали в магазине а не на почте. Не думаю что она прошитая

Comment: Без роутера напрямую Ваш пров позволяет подключаться? Проверить что не прошит роутер можно либо долго ковыряя его либо убрав его из цепочки.

Comment: @alex Roosso вы имеете ввиду NAT? Или как?

Comment: Вообще я не системщик что бы очень. Но думаю что провайдер вас и других абонентов заключил в одну сетку (как были популярны всякие городские локалки)... и там вас перемашрутизирует вас на локалхост... Вообще реально, без пол-литра кажется тут не разобраться сходу.

Comment: @alex Roosso Я тоже не системщик и не очень в этом разбираюсь но такое ограничение интернета это перебор. Взял пол литра и советуюсь с вами изучая разные штуки. Спасибо за рассуждение

Comment: Платные VPN ваш выход... Как вариант. Хотя провайдер если захочет отрежет Вас от них.